# How to avoid default init parameters redundancy in subclasses?

Tags: swift, generics, default-value

I want to provide default values for certain initialization parameters. I would expect to be able to reuse the same default values in subclasses but not finding a way to do this.

First try - parameter defaults:

```
class A { 

    typealias Mapper = (A) -> String

    let mapper: Mapper

    init(mapper: Mapper = {a in "foo"}) {
        self.mapper = mapper
    }

}

class B: A {

    let myVar: Int

    init(myVar: Int, mapper: Mapper = {a in "foo"}) {
        self.myVar = myVar

    }
}

let b: B = B(myVar: 1)
let str = b.mapper(b)
let b2: B = B(myVar: 2, mapper: {a in "bar"})
```

I have to specify the default value twice (in A and in B init) to be able to initialize B with or without default value.

I also tried with convenience initializer, same problem:

```
class A {

    typealias Mapper = (A) -> String

    let mapper: Mapper

    convenience init() {
        self.init(mapper: {a in "foo"})
    }

    init(mapper: Mapper) {
        self.mapper = mapper
    }

}

class B: A {

    let myVar: Int

    convenience init(myVar: Int) {
        self.init(myVar: myVar, mapper: {a in "foo"})
    }

    init(myVar: Int, mapper: Mapper) {
        self.myVar = myVar

        super.init(mapper: mapper)
    }
}
```

I thought maybe at least I put the default value in a static variable, like this:

```
class A {

    typealias Mapper = (A) -> String

    static let defMapper: Mapper = {a in "foo"}

    let mapper: Mapper

    convenience init() {
        self.init(mapper: A.defMapper)
    }

    init(mapper: Mapper) {
        self.mapper = mapper
    }

}

class B: A {

    let myVar: Int

    convenience init(myVar: Int) {
        self.init(myVar: myVar, mapper: A.defMapper)
    }

    init(myVar: Int, mapper: Mapper) {
        self.myVar = myVar

        super.init(mapper: mapper)
    }
}
```

(also possible to define the variable as lazy to avoid initialization when the default parameter is not used).

This works until I add a generic type to A. Then I get "static properties not yet supported in generic types". So I would have to put the default outside the class, which leads to also have to put the typealias definition outside the class, and if I add generics into the mix this is quite a mess.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a computed property:

```
class A<T> {

typealias Mapper = (A) -> String

static var defMapper: Mapper {
    return { a in "foo" }
}

let mapper: Mapper

convenience init() {
    self.init(mapper: A.defMapper)
}

init(mapper: Mapper) {
    self.mapper = mapper
}

}

class B<T>: A<T> {

    let myVar: Int

    convenience init(myVar: Int) {
        self.init(myVar: myVar, mapper: A.defMapper)
    }

    init(myVar: Int, mapper: Mapper) {
        self.myVar = myVar

        super.init(mapper: mapper)
    }
}

let b: B = B<String>(myVar: 1)

let str = b.mapper(b)

let b2: B = B<String>(myVar: 2, mapper: {a in "bar"})

A<Int>(mapper: {a in "bar"})

A<Int>()
```

or a type method:

```
class A<T> {

    typealias Mapper = (A) -> String

    static func defMapper() -> Mapper {
        return { a in "foo" }
    }

    let mapper: Mapper

    convenience init() {
        self.init(mapper: A.defMapper())
    }

    init(mapper: Mapper) {
        self.mapper = mapper
    }

}

class B<T>: A<T> {

    let myVar: Int

    convenience init(myVar: Int) {
        self.init(myVar: myVar, mapper: A.defMapper())
    }

    init(myVar: Int, mapper: Mapper) {
        self.myVar = myVar

        super.init(mapper: mapper)
    }
}

let b: B = B<String>(myVar: 1)

let str = b.mapper(b)

let b2: B = B<String>(myVar: 2, mapper: {a in "bar"})

A<Int>(mapper: {a in "bar"})

A<Int>()
```

Comment: Ahh, didn't think about that. I thought I was missing something related with the initializers so I didn't explore the "alternative way" enough. Thanks!